# Book: Beginners guide for Web Servers, App Servers

Tags: web, server-side

I would like to know useful resources / books which will help in learning about Web Servers, App Servers and basics of web architecture as a beginner.

I am trying to learn how different servers interact with each other. How the browser sends requests to the server and server sends a response. I am interested in learning the inside flows of this process.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to learn about services including (but not limited to) TCP/IP, DNS and HTTP. You will also need at least a basic understanding of routers, switches, cables and the like.

Mike Meyer's CompTIA Network+ [study guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071789227) will tell most of what you need to know to hit the ground running. The guide comes with a timeline of technologies and protocols, down to cable standards. It eventually hits TCP/IP.

Also check out [Wiley's Networking Self-Teaching Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470402385). It focuses less on hardware near the beginning of the book to leave more room for the concept of networking itself.

If you want to back away from books for a bit when it comes to web servers... Well, just work with this [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1_____enUS424US424&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+set+up+a+web+server#hl=en&safe=off&rlz=1C1_____enUS424US424&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+to+set+up+an+apache+web+server&oq=how+to+set+up+an+apache+web+server&aq=f&aqi=g-s2g-K2&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0i10l2j0i30l2.6320.7583.0.7702.8.8.0.0.0.1.98.482.8.8.0...0.0.KhI1-OsYXYw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=15d75812b8b4e1a0&biw=2133&bih=1061) for working with an Apache (HTTP server) installation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. At his point of time, I am really looking at server side architecture. Some keywords which I came across are JSP, Servlet, Tomcat, Web Services, REST etc. I would like to learn more about these in order to connect these so that I can understand the big picture.